# Changes in /etc/lightdm.conf.d/*conf or /etc/lightdm.conf makes any difference

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, lightdm, login-screen

I am trying to make my lightdm use a correct setup of my displays both for login and session.

I have most likely misunderstood something here, but by reading the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) I did the following:

I have tried adding these lines in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` and `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`, but none of these actions make any difference.

I ran both the commented `xrandr` command and the script that runs it to be sure that was not the problem.

```
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
# login-screen
display-setup-script=/usr/share/3head.sh
#display-setup-script=xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output Unknown-0 --off --output DVI-I-0 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-5 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 3610x0 --rotate left --output DP-4 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 1050x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off

$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
# desktop session
session-setup-script=/usr/share/3head.sh
#session-setup-script=xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output Unknown-0 --off --output DVI-I-0 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-5 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 3610x0 --rotate left --output DP-4 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 1050x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
```

in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` i just added both these config files with the exception that I define greeter-session and user-session at the beginning

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/3head.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 343 jan.   7 21:30 /usr/share/3head.sh
```

and the content is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output Unknown-0 \
 --off --output DVI-I-0 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-5 --mode 1680x1050 \
 --pos 3610x0 --rotate left --output DP-4 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 2560x1600 \
 --pos 1050x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-0 --off
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to uncomment those lines.